codeigniter 4 builder returns ( select * ) resultset instead my builded query
In my model I have this method:
public function getTipologiaPrestazioniFromUserId($userId)  
{
    $builder = null;

    if ( (int)$userId > 0 ){

        $builder = $this->db->table('crm_prestazione_tipologia pt')  
->select('pt.id, pt.nome, pt.codice, pt.image, rpt.id_prestazioneTipologia,ur.id_role', false)                                 ->join('crm_roleToPrestazioneTipologia rpt', rpt.id_prestazioneTipologia=pt.id', 'inner')                                 ->join('crm_usertorole ur', 'ur.id_role = rpt.id_role', 'inner')                                 ->join('crm_user u', 'u.id=ur.id_user', 'inner')  
->where('u.id = ', $userId);  
        $exitQuery = $builder->getCompiledSelect();  
        $totalRec  = $builder->countAllResults();  
        $results   = $builder->get()->getResultArray();  
        file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/public/prestazioneTipologia.txt', $exitQuery , FILE_APPEND);  
        if ( $totalRec > 0 ) {  
            file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/public/prestazioneTipologia.txt', print_r($results, true) , FILE_APPEND);  
            return $results;  
        }

    }  
     return false; 
}

result query is :
SELECT pt.id, pt.nome, pt.codice, pt.image,
rpt.id_prestazioneTipologia,ur.id_role 
FROM crm_prestazione_tipologia pt 
INNER JOIN crm_roleToPrestazioneTipologia rpt ON rpt.id_prestazioneTipologia=pt.id 
INNER JOIN crm_usertorole ur ON ur.id_role = rpt.id_role 
INNER JOIN crm_user u ON u.id=ur.id_user 
WHERE u.id = '26'

If I execute the query in my phpMyAdmin page, I get only 1 result, but the function returns a resultset of the select * from crm_prestazione_tipologia  query.
What's wrong in my function?
I tried to debug my script as written.
